How To Hide Background Image and Command Suggestions in Visual Studio Code
Does anyone know how to hide this background image and/or the command suggestions that are displayed by visual studio code when all files are closed?
background i am referring to
I've done a search on google and here on stack overflow for help but have not found any specific advice.
I was expecting this to be something that can be configured in the settings.
